# Amount of Azure SQL Database space required

Tags: azure-sql-server

I want to save the addresses of some 100,000 people in Azure SQL Database. The schema for the address table will look like this.

The size of each table field is 250 NVARCHAR.

`First Name
Middle Name
Last Name
Email
Phone 1
Phone 2
Phone 3
Fax 1
Twitter
Facebook
LinkedIn
Address 1
Address 2
City
State
Country`

- How much GB of storage I need to store 100,000 addresses and the additional space required by the SQL Server?
- Does Microsoft Azure charge for accessing the server to retrieve or save data per call?

Answer (score 0):

The [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/) is suitable for managing large amount of people and their data.